# How to get image URL without downloading?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-storage

There is a way to download, like below:

```
const image = await storage.child('img/'+usrname+'.jpg').getDownloadURL();
this.setState({image});
```

But What I want?

I want to get image as directly, like below:

```
https://firebase.google.com/storage/img/@david.jpg
https://firebase.google.com/storage/img/@jack.jpg
https://firebase.google.com/storage/img/@harry.jpg
```

Why I want like above.

because I have a list of users with name, phone and username, there I saved the image of every user by his/her username(username.jpg).

Now when I list the users I used a loop, like below:

```
users = [];
for(let i=0; i<usersData.length; i++){
  const user = {
         name: usersData[i].name,
         phone: usersData[i].phone,
         image: 'https://firebase.google.com/storage/img/'+usersData[i].username
   }
  users.push(user);
}
```

Note:
 Dont be confused about url (**https://firebase.google.com/storage/**) ,I just gave an example.

Comment: The question is unclear. Your asking how to get the image URL without downloading but that's what happens when your read a node from the Firebase Realtime Database or Firestore - you're just getting the url, but not downloading from Storage. Can you clarify the question?

Comment: Hello @Jay, thank you
For Example:
Suppose I an Image in my website host like:
`https://mywebsite.com/images/david.jpg`
Here when use it in `react-native`, the avbove image I will use it like below:

`<Image
     style={{width: 50, height: 50}}
     source={{uri: 'https://mywebsite.com/images/david.jpg'}}
 />`

Here as you can see I dont need to first put Image link to firebase database and then read image link from database, then load the image.
Here I have access directly the image url.
I hope I can understand you

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Firebase gives us direct link as this

```
https://firebase.google.com/storage/img/@david.jpg
https://firebase.google.com/storage/img/@jack.jpg
```

Because it does not include any project specific data (*Like your storage bucket name, your project ID, token for authentication and so*) in this form of URL. *And if you think you will find that it increases the security to your files in the storage, as no-one can make a random guess to get the access to your storage data* .

In your case you might have to go somewhat in this direction.
Here, we are first iterating through the userData list to aggregate all the promises using `Promise.all` after that in the `then` we get the list of resolved `promises` inside which our url for the image exists.
In last we set various property on our `user` object and push it to the users array.

```
users = [];
userPromise = Promise.all(

    userData.map(data => 
    firebase.storage()
    .refFromURL('gs://<your bucket here>/img')
    .child( data.username+'.jpg' ).getDownloadURL()

    ) 
)
.then(ImgUrls =>{
    ImgUrls.map((ImgUrl,i) => {
        console.log(ImgUrl)
        const user ={
            name:userData[i],
            phone: usersData[i].phone,
            image: ImgUrl

        }
        console.log(user);
        users.push(user);
    });
});
console.log(users);
```